# how can i route multi instance that are from the same one component and keep themself state in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

i might not be able to describe that issue very exact in title.

the premise:

```
// in main layout page
<keep-alive>
  <router-view />
</keep-alive>

// and i have a route
{ path: "something/:id", name: "something", component: () => import("something.vue") }
```

then i nav to it

```
this.$router.push({
          name: "something",
          params: { "id": 123, ... } // and more params
        });
```

so far, all is normal.

but, when i push the same name again with other params value (the id is 456):

```
// something.vue

// the param is new value (456), no problem
{{$route.params.id}}
// but the other data value is kept previous route, like:
{{ count }}
<q-btn label="add" @click="add" />

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

let me rearrange it.

1. push id 123
2. the param value is right (123), the count value is 1
3. click "add" button, count value is 2
4. push id 456
5. the param value is right (456)
6. !!! the count value is 2, !!! it's not what i want

i want to the count value follow route path, meaning that all data state in different route is independent

Comment: Component instance is per route. You can reset a state on route update.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to the same route but with different parameter - Vue reuses the component instance without first destroying then recreating it. You should use the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook to catch this - or put a watcher on `$route` (and then check whether the new route is still the same name).

More information is in the manual - https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Answer (score 0):

actually, i abandoned my idea.

now i try to use component element to solution

```
<keep-alive :include="views">
  <component :is="view" />
</keep-alive>
```

Comment: i got  a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67686238/issue-vuex-do-not-mutate-vuex-store-state-outside-mutation-handlers-problem-w