# issue '[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers problem when i extend' component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i used vuex store in a vue file

```
// a.vue
// use mapGetters
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      appSize: "view/appSize"
    })
  }
}

// appSize is accessed elsewhere, and no actions operation
```

It works fine

===============

but when i extend this component, and set it a new dynamic name:

```
// layout.vue

const allViewPages = {};
let requireViewComponent = require.context(
  "src/pages",
  true,
  /Page.*\.vue$/
);
requireViewComponent.keys().forEach(fn => {
  let comp = requireViewComponent(fn);
  let key = fn.replace(/^\.\/(.*)\.\w+$/, "$1");

  const origin = comp.default;
  origin.data["origin"] = true;
  const proto = Vue.extend(origin);
  allViewPages[key] = proto;
});

function switchView(vm, to) {
  const original = allViewPages[to.uri];

  this.permittedPageViews.push(dynamicName);
  vm.pageView = original.extend({
    name: dynamicName, // a random name for a same vue file component
    data: function() {
      return to.args || {}; // arguments
    }
  });
}
```

`vm.pageView` is layout file data, for:

```
// layout.vue

<keep-alive :include="permittedPageViews">
  <component :is="pageView" />
</keep-alive>
```

then i got error:
`[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

i modify any of the data value in layout file, i get this error

Answer (score 0):

You can not change data from `vuex` store outside a `mutation`. so every time you want to change the value from the store, you need to create a `mutation` for it, and call it from your component. for more information you can see [vuex mutations docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Comment: i didn't try to change store state, just get it.

Comment: maybe cause that i invoke extend tiwce

Comment: Is permittedPageViews in the store?